# How to get the count corresponding to each row in the dataframe and get the individual contribution in percentage in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I am getting the Names of the users in the first column and the amount of work days for them. I want to calculate the contribution of each user in percent. I tried converting it to a list but didn't get much efficient help out of it. Anyone has any suggestions or solutions?

```
   Name    count
0  User_1      3
1  User_2      5
2  User_3      2
3  User_4      2
4  User_5      8
```

So I want the User and its percentage contribution so that I can use it in the dash. (For example user_1 contribution is 3/20 i.e. 15% and so on)

Answer (score 0):

just divide the value_counts by the sum of the value counts like this

```
df.workdays.value_counts()/df.workdays.value_counts().sum()*100
```

Hope this works :)

Comment: thanks for the response. Is it advisable though? What if the dataset is large?

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can set it as new column as well.

```
x = ['User_1','User_2','User_3','User_4','User_5']
y = [3,5,2,2,8]
bd = pd.DataFrame({'Name':x,'count':y})

bd['in % of total'] = bd['count']/ bd['count'].sum()*100

print(bd)


    Name    count   in % of total
0   User_1  3           15.0
1   User_2  5           25.0
2   User_3  2           10.0
3   User_4  2           10.0
4   User_5  8           40.0


print( bd[['Name','in % of total']] )



    Name    in % of total
0   User_1  15.0
1   User_2  25.0
2   User_3  10.0
3   User_4  10.0
4   User_5  40.0
```